# Return XPath attribute value with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to evaluate XML documents with this kind of structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Service_name version="3.3.0">
...
```

where `Service_name` tag name is not constant string, while `version` attribute is required.

For that purpose this xpath expression: `/*[1]/@version` evaluates fine with any xpath processor, but I can't figure how with Python ElementTree.

For example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.parse('sample.xml')
v = find('/*[1]/@version').text
```

raises `KeyError: '@'`

I tried similar combinations but none that worked.

How can I get version number from above example document with ElementTree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElementTree uses its own path syntax, which is more or less a subset of xpath. If you want an ElementTree compatible library with full xpath support, try [lxml](http://lxml.de).

Comment: Yes, I use lxml myself, but working on a part of code that should not require additional modules except SPL.

Comment: Then you'll have to select the element using the path syntax, and retrieve the attribute with the `.get()` method: `doc.find('/*[1]').get('version')` (theta's answer is easier if you know it is the root element)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not XPath as question name, this seems like one way:

`doc.getroot().get('version')`