# Python Regex Google App Engine

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python on GAE

I'm trying to get the following from html

```
<TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V1068078</FONT></TD>
```

I want to get everything that will have a "V" followed by 7 or more digits and have  behind it.

My regex is

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
tree = etree.HTML(html)
mls = tree.xpath('/[V]\d{7,10}</FONT>')
self.response.out.write(mls)
```

It's throwing out an invalid expression.  I don't know what part of it is invalid because it works on the online regex tester

How can i do this in the xpath format?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re

>>> s = '<TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V1068078</FONT></TD>'

>>> a = re.search(r'(.*)(V[0-9]{7,})',s)

>>> a.group(2)
'V1068078'
```

**EDIT**

`(.*)` is a greedy method. `re.search(r'V[0-9]{7,}',s)` will do the extraction with out greed.

**EDIT** as @Kaneg said, you can use `findall` for all instances. You will get a list with all occurrences of `'V[0-9]{7,}'`

Comment: thanks Suku.  If i want to use xpath, what should i do in that case?

Comment: What's the point of doing a greedy search `(.*)` at the beginning of the search?

Comment: @MartinKonecny , yea right. We don't need it here. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do this in the XPath?

You can use [`starts-with()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) here.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> html = '<TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V1068078</FONT></TD>'
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(html)
>>> mls  = tree.xpath("//TD/FONT[starts-with(text(),'V')]")[0].text
'V1068078'
```

Or you can use a regular expression

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> html = '<TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V1068078</FONT></TD>'
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(html)
>>> mls  = tree.xpath("//TD/FONT[re:match(text(), 'V\d{7,}')]", 
           namespaces={'re': 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'})[0].text
'V1068078'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
result = re.search(r'V\d{7,}',s)
print result.group(0)  # prints 'V1068078'
```

It will match any string of numeric digit of length 7 or more that follows the letter `V`

**EDIT**

If you want it to find all instances, replace `search` with `findall`

```
s = '<TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V1068078</FONT></TD>V1068078   V1068078   V1068078'
re.search(r'V\d{7,}',s)
['V1068078', 'V1068078', 'V1068078', 'V1068078']
```

Comment: Yes, updated my answer if you want to find more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Below example can match multiple cases:

```
import re
s = '<TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V10683333</FONT></TD>,' \
' <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V1068333333</FONT></TD>'
m = re.findall(r'V\d{7,}', s)
print m
```

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that keeps posting purely regex solutions, you need to read the question -- the problem is not just formulating a regular expression; it is an issue of isolating the right nodes of the XML/HTML document tree, upon which regex can be employed to subsequently isolate the desired strings.

You didn't show any of your import statements -- are you trying to use ElementTree? In order to use ElementTree you need to have some understanding of the structure of your XML/HTML, from the root down to the target tag (in your case, "TD/FONT"). Next you would use the ElementTree methods, "find" and "findall" to traverse the tree and get to your desired tags/attributes.

As has been [noted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209092/return-xpath-attribute-value-with-elementtree), "ElementTree uses its own path syntax, which is more or less a subset of xpath. If you want an ElementTree compatible library with full xpath support, try [lxml](http://lxml.de/)." ElementTree does have support for [xpath](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), but not the way you are using it here.

If you indeed do want to use ElementTree, you should provide an example of the html you are trying to parse so everybody has a notion of the structure. In the absence of such an example, a made up example would look like the following:

```
import xml, urllib2
from xml.etree import ElementTree


url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04637.xml"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(html)
# namespace prefix, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249876/alter-namespace-prefixing-with-elementtree-in-python
ns = '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}'
root = tree.getiterator(ns+'uniprot')[0]
taxa = root.find(ns+'entry').find(ns+'organism').find(ns+'lineage').findall(ns+'taxon')
for taxon in taxa:
  print taxon.text

# Output:
Eukaryota
Metazoa
Chordata
Craniata
Vertebrata
Euteleostomi
Mammalia
Eutheria
Euarchontoglires
Primates
Haplorrhini
Catarrhini
Hominidae
Homo
```

Answer (score 0):

And the one without capturing groups.

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '<TD><FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-2">V1068078</FONT></TD>'
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=>)V\d{7}', str)
>>> print m.group(0)
V1068078
```